# How can I pass values from one function to HTML when I call JS method back?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
var sno=10;
row.insertCell(6).innerHTML="input type='button' value='edit' onclick='editRecord('sno');'";
```

I want to pass `sno` value to another function.

```
function editRecord(mySno){}
```

Comment: Er, `editRecord(sno)`?

Comment: Try `editRecord(sno)`

Comment: You can assign it to a variable `var variable=sno` then pass `variable` to other function

Comment: actual that is global variable it increase for every row.. i try editRecord(sno) but it takes global variable value(last row value) @Andy

Comment: @ZainFarooq dafuq really? That doesnt make sense ^^

Comment: @manishankarsirisipalli Ah I think you want to pass the variable to the function everytime it changes without calling the function again?

Comment: i try like that also its not working Uncaught ReferenceError: variable  is not definedonclick @ Assignment2.html:1 @ZainFarooq

Comment: @Tom Doodler he want to pass sno to other function. May be sno is not global variable. He can declare a global variable and assign sno to that variable

Comment: Why are you using sno in `onclick='editRecord('sno');`

Comment: you can also write `onclick=editRecord();`

Comment: it is totally unclear what are you asking? please explain in more detail..

Answer (score 2):

Try to not mix codes.

### Creating an HTML Element

```
var newRow = row.insertCell(6),
      input = document.createElement('input');
```

This method is not just faster than the string innerHTML, it will allow you to handle the input as a JavaScript object.

```
input.type = 'button';
input.value = 'edit';
input.onclick = editRecord;
```

You have created a new row, but if you were not creating a new one, you can clear the code inside the row:

```
newRow = (function clearHtmlElement (el){
    var newEl = el.cloneNode();
    el.parentNode.replaceChild(newEl, el);
    return newEl;
}(newRow));
```

And finally append the input to the row element:

```
newRow.appendChild(input);
```

### Saving your Value in the HTML Element scope

Then you are ready to save your value using attributes:

```
input.dataset.sno = 10;
```

or

```
input.setAttribute('data-sno', 10);
```

Or you can save it into the HTML Element:

```
input.sno = 10;
```

### Using your value in your function

```
function editRecord () {
    var sno = this.sno
           || this.getAttribute('data-snow')
           || this.dataset.snow;
    ...
}
```

Choose your way to use it or use them all as I did here. Now you have `sno` available in your function and more important, **it can be the JavaScript object you want**.

---

#### UPDATE: to fit to the use of the function

If you want to use your function as defined on the problem, you'll have to do this trick, when you define the onclick handler:

```
input.onclick = (function(){
    var mySno = sno;
    return function(){
        editR(mySno);
    };
}());
```

here, using the scope, `mySno` will save the reference of the value of `sno` every time you define the onclick handler. BUT **this will not work for objects**, so only numbers or strings will work... plus it's a little bit ugly.

Answer (score 1):

When `sno` is an integer

```
var sno=10; 
row.insertCell(6).innerHTML="input type='button' value='edit' onclick='editRecord(" + sno + ");'";
```

When `sno` is a character

```
var sno='C'; 
row.insertCell(6).innerHTML="input type='button' value='edit' onclick='editRecord(\'"+ sno +"\');'";
```

Answer (score 0):

`editRecord('sno');` is passing the string 'sno', you need to pass the variable like so: `editRecord(sno);`

Comment: its not working... actual that is global variable that is increase row by row its gives last row value

Answer (score 0):

Use the below line I have written for you :

**Code**

```
var sno=10;
    row.insertCell(6).innerHTML="input type='button' value='edit' onclick='editRecord(\'"+sno+"\');'";
```

Comment: its not working error:uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token

Comment: try after removing both the slashes (\)

Answer (score 0):

Never you cant use double quat in double quat or single in single.
Its not true.
"xxxxx"yyyyy"xxxx"
you can use 
"xxxxx'yyyyy'xxxxx"
Or
"xxxxx\"yyyyy\"xxxx"
Or
"xxxx"+"yyyyy"+"xxxx"

var sno=10;
row.insertCell(6).innerHTML="input type='button' value='edit' onclick='editRecord('+sno+');'";

Answer (score -1):

You are passing it already with this line: onclick='editRecord(sno);'

Just remove the ' from sno.